# Regioselectivity in electrophilic substitution of pyrrole

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, regioselectivity

In the electrophilic aromatic substitution (EAS) of pyrrole, why is the alpha position preferred over the beta position so much?

[image: Alpha and beta carbons of pyrrole]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following figure shows the resonance structures we can draw to describe the intermediates produced by electrophilic at the 2- ($\alpha$) or 3- ($\beta$) positions in pyrrole.

[image]

[image source](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/heterocy.htm)

You can see that the intermediate produced by attack at the $\alpha$-position can be described by 3 resonance structures.  Whereas attack at the $\beta$-position produces an intermediate that can be described by only 2 resonance structures.

Therefore, the intermediate formed by $\alpha$ attack is more stable and the activation energy leading to it will be reduced.  Consequently, electrophilic attack at the $\alpha$ position in pyrrole is preferred.